# can two applications in android communicate using local sockets?

Tags: android, security, sockets

i have a question in android documentation it is mentioned that android process can communicate using local sockets. does it mean that two applications with different user id can communicate using local sockets and by that "bypass" the sandbox?

Comment: can you share a link to the docs?

Comment: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/#interprocess-communication

Comment: Fundamentally, trying to prevent cooperating apps from sharing data is a losing proposition, as it quickly starts to impede basic functionality while still remaining weak against determined circumvention.  Android users would be much better served if the platform gave them an ability to line-item-veto unjustified application access to private data in the first place.

Comment: so do you think the sandbox doesn't provide any protection from an application communicating with other applications using local sockets?

Comment: Historically it has not.  It's possible such was added in the multiuser modifications of late, but hopefully not as such measures tend to limit legitimate uses while providing little obstacle to misuse.  Generally one doesn't open a socket by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do IPC using local sockets on Android, see `LocalSocketServer` and `LocalSocket` classes. These translate to UNIX sockets in the abstract namespace.

A word of warning though: Samsung has started restricting local socket use in certain cases through SELinux in their latest firmwares (unfortunately they do not use the same policies as AOSP). I'm not completely clear on the details, but I have seen instances where SELinux blocked the local socket from connecting on these firmwares. Probably depends on the SELinux context of the different processes trying to use the local socket not matching. Be sure to test that if you end up going this route.

Comment: Now it is prohibited https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806516/avc-denied-connectto-when-using-uds-on-android-10