# Android mechanism for processes synchronization

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, synchronization, semaphore

For exchanging information between two processes in android, I am using shared memory. But in order to avoid the situation of parallel writing/reading I need some kind of synchronization between those two processes (classical producer-consumer issue).

The standard approach would be to use Semaphores. However they seems to be not supported in Android (see the implementation on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pthreads/+/master/sem_open.c).

After some research I've found out that for the process synchronization the approach with the File Locks could be used (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html). This would be a perfect solution for me, however our apps should not declare WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, therefore we cannot lock on the "real" file. I've tried the approach on the locking on the shared memory object itself, by using its File Descriptor. Unfortunately this did not work. It seems that for FileLock the "real" file object is required.

I've done a lot of searching, from what I have found out, most of the classical ipc synchronization mechanisms are not supported and in the Android world the Binder usage is the preferred IPC mechanism.

My question is, how could the Semaphore-like mechanism be implemented with the binder (or any other alternative). Of course we could create AIDL with

- isLocked
- lock
- release

set of methods. But it would mean that there will be **"busy waiting"** approach needed (before each write/read operation), which we want to avoid.

Are there any synchronization mechanisms/patterns (either Java or NDK) that we could use?

Comment: How about designing the IPC in lock-free way? (Like something like two queues, the shared memory would have two separate parts, each modified by other process only, and after preparing pack of data for other process there would be some kind of flag to make whole pack of new data legit upon next read from the other process, which will then process those and let know first process in it's own batch of data later, that processing was done and that data pack can be discarded). (I never did this on Android, so I'm not aware of any Android specific problems of such solution)

Comment: Hi Ped7g, thank you for the idea! Yes, I was thinking about something similar, second memory could be used as a flag which indicates if the memory is ready for reading. But I believe it would require the busy waiting too: consumer process would need to poll the value constantly. I am not sure if it is safe as well: writing to this second memory (flag) is also non-atomic operation. Therefore I am seeking for a mechanisms that is working on the OS level, which would address all those issues: atomic operations and notifying the waiting object

Comment: Would traditional `pipe()` or `socket(AF_UNIX)` be an adequate alternative to shared memory based approach, that you've chose? To avoid R/W waiting you may utilize `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

Comment: Hi Sergio, that sounds like an alternative. Basically we want to transfer quite a big buffer between two processes at a high rate. I think that socket could be similar in the performance as the shared memory. I have found following thread on the SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882648/can-two-applications-in-android-communicate-using-local-sockets It seems it should be possible (even in standard java api), however it is not sure how secure such approach is. It is mentioned that Samsung devices (which are also our target) are restricting such usage.